# Difference between Classic and Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I am learning about AWS elastic and classic load balancer. I understand what a load balancer does, but can someone please explain what the difference is between them?

I'm studying for a AWS certificate and I need to be able to explain the difference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

Comment: You seem to have your terms confused. There are three types of AWS Elastic Load Balancers: Classic Load Balancer, Application Load Balancer, and Network Load Balancer. Originally there was only the Classic Load Balancer, which was simply called an Elastic Load Balancer.

Comment: @MarkB, it seems I did. Much easier to get my head around now I understand that there are three! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you have three types of Elastic Load Balancer (ELB).

> You can select the appropriate load balancer based on your application needs. If you need flexible application management, we recommend that you use an **Application Load Balancer**. If extreme performance and static IP is needed for your application, we recommend that you use a **Network Load Balancer**. If you have an existing application that was built within the EC2-Classic network, then you should use a **Classic Load Balancer**.

That's from the AWS ELB page, see a feature comparison and description of each service here: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/

Answer (score 0):

The AWS api and documentation is very confusing about load balancers.

First release of LoadBalancer (TCP load balancer only) was called ELB for Elastic LoadBalancer.

Second and actual release of load balancers are called ALB for Application Load Balancer. They deal with TCP/HTTP/HTTPS, filtering rules, etc. Be carefull, in the API ALB are called LoadBalancer_v2 !!!

Comment: Easily confused then haha! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 we have Gateway Load Balancer in addition.
So there are 4 Balancers:

- Application Load Balancer - HTTP, HTTPS, gRPC (for IP, Instance, Lambda),
- Network Load Balancer - TCP, UDP, TLS (for IP, Instance, App.. Load Balancer),
- Gateway Load Balancer - IP (for IP, Instance),
- Classic Load Balancer - SSL/TLS, HTTP, HTTPS (for classic EC2-networks).

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/